# Creating a while loop in Rock Paper Scissors game for Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am very new to programming and looking for some help with a homeowner assignment. The assignment is as follows:

Write a program using default python functions that lets the user play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors against the computer.  The program should work as follows:

1. When the program begins, a random number in the range of 1 through 3 is generated. If the number is 1, then the computer has chosen rock. If the number is 2, then the computer has chosen paper, if the number is 3, then computer has chosen scissors.
2. The user enters his or her choice of "rock", "paper" or "scissors" at the keyboard.
3. The computer's choice is displayed.
4. A winner is selected according to the following rules.

The game should end when either the computer or user has won a single round and continue when the result as a draw. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 from random import randint

 #create a list of play options
 t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

 #assign a random play to the computer
 computer = t[randint(1,3)]

 #set player to False
 player = False

 while player == False:
 #set player to True
     player = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
     if player == computer:
         print("Tie!")
     elif player == "Rock":
         if computer == "Paper":
             print("You lose!", computer, "covers", player)
         else:
             print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)
     elif player == "Paper":
         if computer == "Scissors":
             print("You lose!", computer, "cut", player)
         else:
             print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)
     elif player == "Scissors":
         if computer == "Rock":
             print("You lose...", computer, "smashes", player)
         else:
             print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
     else:
         print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")
      #player was set to True, but we want it to be False so the loop continues
     player = False
     computer = t[randint(1,3)]
```

Comment: The list indexes run from 0 to 2, not 1 to 3.

Comment: Use `computer = random.choice(t)`

Comment: "Any help" is not a Stack Overflow question.  You have already implemented the logic to know whether or not the round is a tie, but you've made no attempt to use that information in your loop control.

Comment: Instead of `while player == False:`, just use `while True:`. When you want to stop the game, use `break`.

Comment: Make a valid attempt to solve the problem.  If you get stuck, see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're looking for open-ended feedback on your code, rather than help with one specific problem, may I recommend https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that you are making a wrong choice for the computer. The lists in Python, as arrays in vast majority of programming languages, start from 0. In your case you are generating a number in range 1 to 3, which is it will never get the first element of `t` and will fail when the number is 3, as the list ends with 2.

For that part you can generate a number from 0 to 2, or use `choice()` method from the `random` module. Please note that you need to import it first.

Also, I'd rather use `while True` with some `break`s rather than the old fashioned state variable.
Here is the working version of your code, made same refactoring:

```
from random import choice

#create a list of play options
t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

while True:
    computer = choice(t)

    player = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")

    if player == computer:
        print("Tie!")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You lose!", computer, "covers", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)
        break
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You lose!", computer, "cut", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)
        break
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You lose...", computer, "smashes", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
        break
    else:
        print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")
```